# Limit to single core for unit test

Tags: junit, concurrency

I have an issue where my unit test currently passes on my dev machine (multi core machine), but the same code fails in pre production (single core machine). 
Is it possible to somehow limit the number of cores available for a unit test to get an equal environment on my dev machine? Unfortunately I'm not able to run the unit tests on the pre prod machine.

Comment: Do your tests explicitly invoke parallelism?  More generally, it sounds like you're saying "my tests pass, but the application fails, so I need to eliminate the difference in # cores".  Why are you sure the cause isn't something else?

Comment: You can get some background in this other thread: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/76266810?noredirect=1
Basically I just want to limit number of cores to see if I can provoke the issue to occur in the unit tests and understand why it is failing in production. I don't really know what the issue is yet...

Comment: Yes that seems reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do that.

- Use **taskset** command

Taskset command binds all threads of a particular process to some subset of cores. Using is easy: taskset -c 0 'your command'

This will bind every thread to the first CPU.

So in order to do this you need to be able to run your unit test programmatically via the command line. If you use some build tool you just run the coommand after taskset. For example

taskset -c 0 "mvn clean compile test"

If you run your test via IDE then you can check full command which is printed when you run the test. In that case it will look like

taskset -c 0 "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java -cp classpath com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter name_of_test"

[More about taskset command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset)

- Use **affinity locks**

Affinity lock can be used programmatically to bind some code to a particular core. But in that case I'm not sure if it will be able to bind also newly created threads during the code execution. I think taskset is easier to use and does all the work.

Check [OpenHFT/Java-Thread-Affinity](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Thread-Affinity) as it's the most popular affinity lock tool for java.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me in the right direction. For anyone on osx (like me) where taskset is not supported, find the appropriate steps here http://jesperrasmussen.com/2013/03/07/limiting-cpu-cores-on-the-fly-in-os-x/